# React-native : detect dev or production env

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I develop a react-native app where some API calls should be made.

If I'm in production mode my app should call, for example, this host :

```
https://example.com/
```

but if I'm in dev mode, it should call my local host machine on a different port, for example :

```
http://192.168.0.10:8080/
```

How the react-native code can be aware of its environment ?

`.dotenv` seems to not work with react-native.

In the Chrome debug, we can see that the application is launched with some params :

```
Running application "AppName" with appParams: {"initialProps":{},"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
```

Can we get this `__DEV__` value in the application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 155, accepted):

## Set automatically

The constant `__DEV__` is set automatically.

### Production

Building the bundle via `--dev=false` should unset `__DEV__`.

### Usage

```
if (__DEV__) {
    console.log('Development');
} else {
    console.log('Production');
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks.

Do you know a way to set env variables ?

Comment: Nope sorry. In my projects I often use a config file, which exports some constants like an API Url. This is useful to create different builds of an app, like beta and production.

Comment: Ok. We exactly don't want different builds.

Comment: see also [Can react-native bundler detect unused files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844101/can-react-native-bundler-detect-unused-files)

Comment: to use `env` file in RN you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv package

Comment: does not work with debug apk, debug apk builds with __dev__ as false

Comment: I would also suggest looking at react-native-config: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config