# How can I determine if my React Native app is a debug or release build from JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'd like to add some debug-only UI to my React Native app, but I can't find any equivalent of `RCT_DEBUG` or `RCT_DEV` compile-time flags in the JavaScript environment. Is there one?

Use case: I want to add a status bar that shows the number of HTTP requests initiated by my app. Obviously this is not part of a shipping app, but it would help me check my work while in development and testing.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34317341/5042391

Answer (score 261, accepted):

```
if (__DEV__) {
    console.log('I am in debug');
}
```

You can [see this approach](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?p=1&q=__DEV__&unscoped_q=__DEV__) is being used in [React Native repository](https://github.com/facebook/react-native).

Comment: is this still valid? if so source please?

Comment: @zianwar https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/packager#pathtomodulenamemapbundle-query-params

Comment: @JamealG "dev boolean, defaults to true: sets a global __DEV__ variable which will effect how the React Native core libraries behave." is the line you're looking for. Good find!

Comment: or just shake it once :P

Comment: it seems to be valid and is used in [AppContainer.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1151c096dab17e5d9a6ac05b61aacecd4305f3db/Libraries/ReactNative/AppContainer.js#L55)

Comment: see also [Can react-native bundler detect unused files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844101/can-react-native-bundler-detect-unused-files)

Comment: does not work with debug apk, debug apk builds with __dev__ as false

Comment: The problem is, i still cannot run console.table when __DEV__ is true, how do i find out whether the react native is in debug mode?

Comment: This doesn't work well for me on React Native 0.63 and Android. `__DEV__` is `true in `staging` builds as well. Maybe `release` as well but I didn't test that.