# Viewing console logs on react-native Android release build

Tags: android, react-native

I'm currently facing an issue which only exists in production/release build for Android. Is it possible to run debugger or view logs for production/release builds?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

Run the logger for android using the following:

```
npx react-native log-android
```

Then run your app in release mode:

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

All of your console.log() and console.warn() should be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `console.log`, `console.warn`, etc.

You can try simply run the following to see logs in the console:

```js
react-native log-ios
react-native log-android
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38056698/9877424

Answer (score 0):

For android
npx react-native run-android --configuration=Release

For IOS
npx react-native run-ios --device "Device_Name" --configuration=Release

Answer (score -4):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315274/react-native-detect-dev-or-production-env/34317341#34317341) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498970/how-can-i-determine-if-my-react-native-app-is-a-debug-or-release-build-from-java) could help.

Try something with

```
if (__DEV__) {
    //log in dev build
} else {
   //log in product build
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this. Took awhile but I managed to locate the issue manually.