# reactjs : detect i'm in dev or test environment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, devops, test-environments

I develop a ReactJS App with TypeScript that calls an api, there are two global environments (dev and test (not production)) with different URLs, for example:

baseurl for dev environment: https://dev.example.com/

baseurl for test environment: https://test.example.com/

so how can I switch between these URLs according to the current environment

here is a similar issue for react-native :
[React-native : detect dev or production env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315274/react-native-detect-dev-or-production-env)

docker and popular DevOps are used in this project (actually I'm not familiar with them, but maybe this information is help).

any suggestions, please
Thank you!

Comment: parse the URL and redirect accordigly

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json you can specify a proxy to these API:s by adding e.g.

```
"proxy": {
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://test.example.com/"
  }
}
```

Which will proxy your request to this host, e.g. if you were to `fetch("api/asd");` you would fetch whatever is at `https://test.example.com/api/asd`.